# Finding mean of a list of values for each year given a certain zip code

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, mean

I want to get the yearly mean of a list of values associated with a zip code the problem I get this error code, can you please help me out.

[image: My DataFrame]

My code is:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
rng = pd.date_range('2/9/2017', '3/19/2019', freq='10T')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'SCORE':np.random.randint(1000, size=len(rng))}, index=rng)
out = pd.Series({x: df2.loc({x: df2.loc[f'02/9/{x}', :f'03/19/{x+1}', 'SCORE'].mean()
                 for x in range(df2.index.year.min(), df2.index.year.max()+1)})
```

The error is:

```
  File "<ipython-input-150-61dcc574e6e3>", line 1
    out = pd.Series({x: df2.loc({x: df2.loc[f'02/9/{x}', :f'03/19/{x+1}', 'SCORE'].mean()
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss a coma between `f'02/9/{x}'` and  `:f'03/19/{x+1}'`:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
rng = pd.date_range('2/9/2017', '3/19/2019', freq='10T')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'SCORE':np.random.randint(1000, size=len(rng))}, index=rng)
out = pd.Series({x: df2.loc({x: df2.loc(f'02/9/{x}', f'03/19/{x+1}', 'SCORE').mean()
                 for x in range(df2.index.year.min(), df2.index.year.max()+1)})
```

Comment: Hello Federico this did not work

Comment: @Khan, I noticed now that there was a `:`   so I correct it, try now

Comment: File "<ipython-input-157-7a40a64464c7>", line 1
    out = pd.Series({x: df2.loc({x: df2.loc[f'02/9/{x}', f'03/19/{x+1}', 'SCORE'].mean()
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: is if df2.loc a function then wrapp it in `()`brackets

Comment: Try now, I change the code again and let me know, if it works remember to vote up my answer

Comment: no it did not work!

Comment: Add the new code and the error please, to the Question and not as a comment otherwise is un readable

Comment: I added it since yesterday

Comment: My man, you added it the first time, then I added my answer (and correct it twice because of the syntax error) despite this you stated that by Copyng my excact code in my answer you still get an error. So I asked you to update the Answer with the new error and then new code snippet, but it's clear that is the old one, otherwise My code and your code would look the same!

Comment: To be honest when I pasted the code I pasted it wrong and then I tried yours which I used but it gave me the same result sorry for what happened, now is there any solution if possible?

Comment: Can you help please